# Sample Flow with last item

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Sample from Kotlin Coroutine https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/sample.html

Doesn't emit the last element if the parent flow is finished before the time frame.

From Docs:
`Note that the latest element is not emitted if it does not fit into the sampling window.`

I want an operator that acts just as the sample but emits the last value when the timeframe reaches.
The last value is important in my case.
Eg code:

```kotlin
val k = (0..100).asFlow().onEach {
        delay(200)
    }

    val k2 = k.sample(500)

    k2.collectLatest {
        println(it)
    }
```

A custom operator would do if none is provided by the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. The code should be self-explanatory. I did not rigorously test it!

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.sampleAndKeepLast(periodMillis: Long): Flow<T> {
    require(periodMillis > 0) { "Sample period should be positive" }
    return channelFlow {
        var isDone = false
        val empty = Any()
        var lastValue: Any? = empty
        onEach { lastValue = it }
            .onCompletion { isDone = true }
            .launchIn(this)
        while (!isDone) {
            delay(periodMillis)
            if (lastValue !== empty) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                send(lastValue as T)
                lastValue = empty
            }
        }
        if (lastValue !== empty) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            send(lastValue as T)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This function is nice. However, the last value is emitted just right after the previous one, without waiting for the periodMillis argument.

```kotlin
val k = (0..100).asFlow().onEach {
        delay(200)
    }

    val k2 = k.sampleAndKeepLast(2000)

    k2.collectLatest {
        println(it)
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? It's waiting when I test that same code. Try it with logging the elapsed time: https://pastebin.com/fJrN5en6

Comment: Yes, my bad. It's working as expected.